# Spring JPA repository @query not able to resolve object name and param name

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a interface where JpaCrmProfile is my entity class :

```
public interface JpaCrmProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<JpaCrmProfile, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT c FROM JpaCrmProfile c WHERE c.domain_id = :domainId AND c.name = :name")
    JpaCrmProfile findOneByDomain(@Param(domainId) Long domainId, @Param(name) String name);
}
```

In IDE ,object name in query JpaCrmProfile  and domainId in @param see in red color with a error msg can't resolve symbol

Comment: Show us the real code, that compiles and actually causes the problem. Not some other made-up code that doesn't even compile. And describe your problem clearly: what is the code that you're executing, and what happens precisely? If you get an exception, what is its stack trace?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `JpaCrmProfile`, is it an entity, do your spring config "scan" it's package? You probably also want to fix the `@Param` annotations

Comment: Dear JB, I am using Intellij Idea IDE , when I am writing that interface object name 'JpaCrmProfile' in query and param name(domainId) show in red color , error show as can't resolve symbol and my JpaCrmProfile is an entity class

Comment: @adrian-b you should not fix OP code in edit, this may lead to bad situations (question no longer valid etc)

Comment: @PrashantAggarwal Intellij should offer you a fix (adding an import maybe)

Comment: Don't trust the IDE. Test the code.

Comment: @jb , ther is no import error because it shows with any error in  extends JpaRepository<JpaCrmProfile, Long>

Comment: @RC I only edited two typos, that I believe were credited to writing the code on SO (one of them at least would have thrown a compiling error). If the code runs ok now, the OP should let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "domain_id" and "name" according to its names in JpaCrmProfile class.

For better help I need code of your JpaCrmProfile class.
Also you can look something here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

PS.I have the same issue now. BUT my application works nice.